# I can't post to an address different to "localhost" using Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a easy web page, I use Angular for client and spring boot for server. First I have done tests using local host, example of my angular app:

This is my service.ts that communicates to java server:

```
url="http//localhost/demo";

login(u:user){
  return this.http.post<user>(this.url+'/login',u);
}
```

The code above works correctly, ok the problem starts when I try to use my domain name assigned to server, to use this app in production.

```
url="http//domain/demo";

login(u:user){
  return this.http.post<user>(this.url+'/login',u);
}
```

I don't know what's happening, I've done test using postman aplication and I can do the post corretly and recived the response using url(http//domain/demo), so the dns,port forwarding and java server are not the problem. I've used wireshark to capture the requests and responses, and I was surprised that not even the request message is generated, is like angular will block the request for not being a localhost url.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Missing `:` into URL, use `url="http://localhost/demo";` instead `url="http//localhost/demo";`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are hitting the limitations enforced by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Only specific set of requests can be done without beeing block by CORS rules - those are called [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests). For every other kind of request, host that you try to connect to must explicitly allow to access its resources from different domain. This is done with so called pre-flight request.

If pre-flight fails - request is blocked. Angular app (any js app) will not be even notified what caused the error. You will simply receive err code 0 (if I remember correctly). Pre-flight can fail if server response does not declare that request from your current domain is allowed (by explicitly mentioning it, or wildcarding it) or if the server didn't respond to the preflight at all.

CORS rules are enforced by the browsers themselves. Therfore you will be able to execute specific requests using eg Wget, CURL, Postman and any other http client and yet the exact same requests will be blocked by the browser. This obviously applies to XHR requests (simple speaking, requests done via JS)

CORS rules does not apply to `localhost`

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, but how I configure my Angular client to allow me to send request to a different domain that localhost ? In my spring boot app I've set the tag "@CrossOrigin(origins="*",maxAge=3600)" in the controller, so the server allows any request. I've investigated and people say that install a plugin but this solution only works if I use command ng serve, in my case I use command ng build --prod and I access to app using apache.

Comment: If you have indeed set `@CrossOrigin` then it will work regardles of run method. Check in the browser console result of the preflight request (OPTIONS)

Comment: I've solved the problem, the error was that I using the same domain name for client and server, so I use port 80 to refer client and port 79 for server, well chrome was blocking me the server 79, Ive changed It for 81 and works. Anyway thanks for the help, I've learned a lot about cors policy.